# Using Redshift on Elementary OS

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I installed Redshift 1.11 on Elementary OS Freya but I noticed that the methods list only mentioned the dummy method (which just displays the target gamma in the terminal).

```
$ redshift -m list
Available adjustment methods:
  dummy
```

This makes it kind of useless...
So I cloned the source, ran `./bootstrap` and then `./configure`. This indicated that it wouldn't have any of the adjustment methods:

```
Adjustment methods:
DRM:        no
RANDR:      no
VidMode:        no
Quartz (OSX):   no
WinGDI (Windows):   no
```

Above it, it indicated missing dependencies:

```
checking whether to enable RANDR method... missing dependencies
checking whether to enable VidMode method... missing dependencies
```

The github repo's Hacking docs lists the [dependencies](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/blob/master/HACKING.md#dependencies):

- libxcb, libxcb-randr (Optional, for RandR support)
- libX11, libXxf86vm
  (Optional, for VidMode support)

These packages I need for Randr or vidmode are not found though.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxcb libxcb-randr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libxcb
E: Unable to locate package libxcb-randr

$ sudo apt-get install libX11 libXxf86vm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libX11
E: Unable to locate package libXxf86vm
```

I'm not sure how to continue. Does anyone have any tips / leads?

Comment: f.lux is not good for you?

Comment: @MaximTaranov good point, but I was trying to use a opensource solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

1. Download latest source from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/releases/download/v1.11/redshift-1.11.tar.xz)
2. Install the required libraries:

   ```
   sudo apt install libxcb1-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libx11-dev intltool
   ```
3. Go to extracted redshift folder, then run these commands:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=$HOME/redshift/root --with-systemduserunitdir=$HOME/.config/systemd/user  --enable-randr
   make; sudo make install
   ~/redshift/root/bin/redshift -l your_latitude:your_longitude
   ```
4. Add the last line to your startup application list

Comment: downvoters, care to explain?

Comment: Awesome, after installing those packages the configure indeed enabled randr and then I could start redshift. And I verified it worked by changing the time to nighttime. 
But why not start `redshift-gtk`? This enables the gui (indicator and menu in the top bar).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to copy the binary / binaries to a $PATH folder after make?

Answer (score 4):

You can install `redshift` from repository ufficial of Ubuntu/Elementary OS.
Just run it in your terminal:

> $ sudo apt-get install redshift redshift-gtk
>
> $ sudo apt-get install libxcb1-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libx11-dev
>
> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ redshift

I've run it and work!

You can use `redshift -h` for help, and you can run `redshift -m list`  and use `randr/vidmode`.

For other help you can use documentation from terminal with `man redshift`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looking at `apt-cache policy redshift` I installed it from the official Ubuntu repository: `http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages`. But even after installing redshift-gtk explicitly and installing those additional packages, libcb1-dev,  libxcb-randr0-dev etc `redshift -m list` still only lists `dummy` as option. 
I understood from the developers that these options are enabled when building the package, depending on which packages are present. Doesn't this make installing those dependencies irrelevant when I don't compile the package myself?

Comment: I can confirm that on ElementaryOS Loki Refshift can be found the AppCenter. But to get it to run I also had to install GeoClue 2 by running `sudo apt install geoclue-2.0`.