# f.lux stops working sometimes when a (native) notification arrives

Tags: release-freya, notifications

I have installed f.lux on my computer. Sometimes suddenly it stops working and the screen turns into the original color, so I have to kill the process and restart it, and then it works again. Any way to solve this problem? Or any similar program?

Comment: Redshift adjusts the color temperature of your screen according to your surroundings. This may help your eyes hurt less if you are working in front of the screen at night. This program is inspired by f.lux .... `sudo apt install redshift`

Comment: For using redshift in elementary check http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/6875/6398

Comment: I installed redshift and it happens with it too. It seems like it is a screen driver issue or something

Comment: I experiences the same issue too. Sometimes, especially in Youtube, it occurs.

Comment: You might want to report a bug here: https://github.com/xflux-gui/xflux-gui/issues